# Recurring nvidia-settings notification

Tags: nvidia, pop-os

Recently, after booting up my laptop, I keep getting this notification on my screen

> "Execution of nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q [GPU]/GPUCoreTemp -q UsedDedicatedGPUMemory -q TotalDedicatedGPUMemory -q GPUCurrentFanSpeed -t failed:: ERROR: Error resolving target specification '' (No targets match target specification), specified in query 'GPUCurrentFanSpeed'."

This particular notification keeps appearing every second and it's distracting.

When I check journalctl, I get the following lines in the log also in repetitive pattern:

```
$ journalctl -xf
Oct 14 16:08:53 pop-os gnome-shell[2695]: error: Execution of
 nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q [GPU]/GPUCoreTemp -q UsedDedicatedGPUMemory
 -q TotalDedicatedGPUMemory -q GPUCurrentFanSpeed -t failed:: ERROR: Error resolving target
 specification '' (No targets match target specification), specified in query 'GPUCurrentFanSpeed'.
```

I'm sure that some parameter is missing from the command that's been executed in the background but I don't know how to stop the error from appearing. So I need help regarding that.

I'm using an HP Pavilion laptop with a GeForce 940MX graphics card and Pop! OS 22.04 with builtin nVidia driver on board.

**Update:** Tried the following command resulting given output. Still no clue how to fix the issue.

```
$ nvidia-settings -q all | grep GPUCurrentFanSpeed

ERROR: The requested operation is not available on target device


ERROR: The requested operation is not available on target device


ERROR: The requested operation is not available on target device


ERROR: The requested operation is not available on target device


ERROR: The requested operation is not available on target device


ERROR: The requested operation is not available on target device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GeForce 940MX doesn't feature a cooling fan, the given query was throwing that error. The query was periodically made by a gnome extension called **Nvidia GPU stats**. Removing nvidia-settings as a source for the extension stopped generating the notification.

[image]